# Zip a Ktor ByteChannel

Tags: kotlin, zip, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I need to consume some data¹ and stream it as part of a zip archive in a multipart request. I'm using a `ByteChannel` but I need something in the middle to zip the written data.
There's Java's `ZipOutputStream`, but that's not async/suspendable and I'm afraid getting an `OutputStream` from the channel and passing that to a zip stream will impact performance in a considerable way.

Is there any better method? If not, which measures can and should I take to minimize the impact of integrating a Java stream with a coroutine-based channel?

Thanks

---

¹ Potentially quite large, hence why I must stream it instead of getting it whole, zipping it and then pushing it elsewhere.

Comment: Do you specifically need to ZIP a stream of data or any other compression method can be used too, e.g. GZip?

Comment: I need to ZIP it because I also need to create an archive with possibly many entries, and ZIP is much more widespread than 7zip or a compressed tarball. 
In fact, I am not really consuming just a single stream of data and compressing it, but rather consuming a sequence of data streams, each being mapped to an entry on the final ZIP file.
If you have suggestions on a better approach for this, let me know!